# MapReduce works when reduce tasks=1 but not when I increase number of reducers?

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce, matrix-multiplication

I'm trying to get through an activity where I need to do some matrix multiplication (M*N) followed by subtraction (X-MN) in a map reduce framework.

I'm currently having a problem where the code I have written seems to work fine when I have 1 reducer task i.e. `-D mapred.reduce.tasks=1` set in my run script, but fails when I increase this. I'm new to MapReduce and I don't really understand what's happening here

My matrices look like the below example, they are all square and the same size (3*3). The only thing that changes between my three input matrices is that the first (M) has `1` as the first value of every line, the second (N) has `2` and the third (X) `3`

M.txt

1, 0, 1, 2, 3

1, 1, 4, 5, 6

1, 2, 7, 8, 9

The mapper I have written looks like this:

```
m_matrix_num = 1
n_matrix_num = 2
x_matrix_num = 3
row = int(sys.argv[1])
col = int(sys.argv[2])
def fill_dictionaries_from_txt(txt_list, matrix_num):
    val_list = []
    val_list.append(txt_list.split(","))
    val = [int(elem) for elem in val_list[0][2:]]
    i = int(val_list[0][1])
    for j in range(col):
        key_name = (matrix_num, i, j)
        print(key_name, val[j])
for line in sys.stdin:
        if line !="\n":
            if line[0]=="1":
                listM_dict = fill_dictionaries_from_txt(line, m_matrix_num)
            if line[0]=="2":
                listN_dict = fill_dictionaries_from_txt(line, n_matrix_num)
            if line[0]=="3":
                listX_dict = fill_dictionaries_from_txt(line, x_matrix_num)
```

The reducer I have written looks like this:

```
import sys
m_matrix_num = 1
n_matrix_num = 2
x_matrix_num = 2
mn_matrix_num = 4
listM_dict = {}
listN_dict = {}
listX_dict = {}
listMN_dict = {}
for line in sys.stdin:
    key_str, val_str = line.split(":")
    key_str = [elem.strip() for elem in key_str if elem.isalnum()]
    key_str = [int(elem) for elem in key_str]
    key = tuple(key_str)
    val = val_str[3:-3]
    val = int(val)
    if key[0] == 1:
        listM_dict[key] = val
    if key[0] == 2:
        listN_dict[key] = val
    if key[0] == 3:
        listX_dict[key] = val
row = max(listM_dict, key=listM_dict.get)[1] + 1
col = max(listM_dict, key=listM_dict.get)[2] + 1
for i in range(row):
    for j in range(col):
        sum = 0
        for k in range(row):
            key_m = (m_matrix_num, i , k)
            key_n = (n_matrix_num, k, j)
            key_mn = (mn_matrix_num, i, j)
            if key_mn in listMN_dict:
                listMN_dict[key_mn] += listM_dict.get(key_m) * listN_dict.get(key_n)
            else:
                listMN_dict[key_mn] = listM_dict.get(key_m) * listN_dict.get(key_n)
for i in range(row):
    for j in range(col):
        key_mn = (mn_matrix_num, i, j)
        key_x = (x_matrix_num, i, j)
        print('%s %s %s' % (i, j, listX_dict.get(key_x) - listMN_dict.get(key_mn)))
```

And finally the script I am using to run the whole thing, looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash  
row=3
column=3
hadoop jar ./hadoop-streaming-3.1.4.jar \
-D mapred.reduce.tasks=3 \
-file ./mapper.py \
-mapper ./mapper.py $row $column \
-file ./reducer.py \
-reducer ./reducer.py \
-input /input \
-output /output
```

My hunch as to why things stop working when I increase the number of reducers is that the mapper outputs become spread out and the multiplication code can't find all of the parts of the dictionary it needs. But I'm not sure if this is correct.

Can you please help me understand why this happens, and how I can modify my code to get it to stop happening?

Please let me know if there's any more information I can add!

Comment: You shouldn't put a space after `-D` for JVM arguments. Also, not clear if you're actually using YARN https://stackoverflow.com/a/24595287/2308683

Comment: Btw, your "fill dictionary" function isn't filling anything. It returns None, and there's no dictionaries. I'm having a hard time understanding what your mapper output actually is. For example, why append a list of split text to the val-list, only then to use `val_list[0]`? Seems like you should be doing `val_list = list(map(int, txt_list.split(",")))`